# Facebook Photo ID

Tags: facebook

Does the Facebook API return the UNIQUE ID of photos I upload to FB through my app?
There are data I would like to keep track of of the photos which Facebook doesn't but I want to present in my app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each photo was specified with a unique "identity", This identity is specified by the user's id and photo's id
A typical url of a photo looks like this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=xxxxxxxx&set=a.xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx&type=3
```

That's a preview mode, in order to access a user's photos you must have also the privileges to access it
Also I know that each photo on fb has a permalink too
Looking like :`http://a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s720x720/xxxx_10150317692149803_5524802_7778361_2055733189_n.jpg`  This is also accessible though fb's sdk but also is under user's privileges

Comment: but how user id can tell us that any particular photo is uploaded by your application?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it does, but you will most likely need the correct photo privilege to retrieve it. Also if your app is posting the photo. It should return the id of the newly created picture

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. When your application uploads any photo of facebook, facebook creates a album with your application name. Now you can grab all photos which have `aid` of your application. For more you can check from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the id is unique. An id also tells us the type of object based on where it is within our global block of ids (FBIDs).